# How do I find the value of this series? $\frac{n^{2k}}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

In my last exam there was a task where we had to find the value of this series:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{n^{2k}}{k!}
$$

I thought about using a ratio test where I did the following:

> $$
> \dfrac{a_{k+1} }{a_{k}} = \frac{\dfrac{n^{2*(k+1)}}{(k+1)!}}{\dfrac{n^2*k}{k!}} = \dfrac{n^{2(k+1)}k!}{(k+1)!*n^{2k}}
> $$

The problem that I have now is that I don't know how to continue or if this the right approach.

Comment: Use the expansion for $e^x$ Note $n^{2k}=(n^2)^k$.

Comment: This is just $e^{n^2}$. Plug $x=n^2$ into the Taylor series of $e^x$

Comment: Using a test for convergence is never going to give you the *value* of a series. It makes no sense to even try that approach.

Comment: The ratio test will test for *convergence* of a series. The above implementation of the test gives $n^2/(k+1)$ but as to the value of the sum, this is not it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Your expression is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{n^{2k}}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n^2)^k}{k!}$$